# Chrome "request does not match recipient windows's origin"

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-chrome, vue.js, request

I am working on a application which has laravel as the backend and vuejs as the frontend. Now I am doing this request but I get an error which obviously just happens on the local development. Is there a way to get around that?

```
async login () {
  const newWindow = openWindow('', 'Title');
  newWindow.location.href = 'http://backend.test/api/login/oauthprovider';
},
```

When this is getting executed I get this error:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://backend.test') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://127.0.0.1:8080').

Can I disable this for developing purposes?

Comment: modify your hosts file, but you still have a port problem

Comment: I have got the backend on the hosts file. But I cannot link the frontend on the same domain as well.

Comment: This appears to be a violation of the same-origin-policy. There is a standard to circumvent the block you've encountered:[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You must have control over the `backend.test` server.

Comment: @Mdspriefield Apparently not.  Make backend.test point to 127.0.0.1, move your server to port 80 and configure whatever IDE you're using to load your test documents from backend.test, not 128.0.0.1.  If you're not already hosting the OAuth provider you're using then you're pretty much out of luck

Comment: @Tibrogargan How do you mean that? I run the backend on a webserver (Laragon)standard on port 80 and my frontend I currently run on a development nodejs server on port 8080. Can I somehow bind both to the same backend.test domain but the frontend listens to port 8080 and the backend on port 80? If yes how?